# Smartphone touchscreen ribbon connector

Tags: pcb, android, touchscreen

Does anyone know what screen connectors or ribbon connectors for a smartphone like the galaxy nexus connecting to it's pcb and if simliar with other phones the screen connector that is, i'm finding it difficult to find what is compatible and not or any infomation on the ribbon connector is their a industry standard for something like that for touchscreens used in smartphones connecting the pcb? is a chipset exclusive setup thanks :)

[image]

Answer (score 4):

FFC/FPC, like Oli says. There are common connectors, or ZIF "Zero Insertion Force" connector. In the latter you first insert the FFC, then click the top part in the bottom part to fix it. ZIF connectors may be handy, since otherwise the FFC may get crooked when inserting; in my experience the insertion force can be rather high. On one occasion we had our toolshop make a special tool for the insertion, when the connector was difficult to reach.

The FFCs are often custom made, as their number of connections, pitch, and length may be different for each other application. Some have reinforced ends ("stiffeners") to cope with the connector's insertion force.

Comment: Thanks guys :) really appreciate the infomation and how informative what's more commonplace in smartphone design stanard ZIF connector or proprietary?

Answer (score 2):

If you are asking about the ribbon connector, they are known as [FFC/FPC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flexible_flat_cable) (flexible flat cable, flexible printed circuit) cables.
For connectors places like Digikey, Mouser, RS, Farnell sell them - here is the [FFC/FPC page at Farnell](http://uk.farnell.com/ffc-fpc).